# Final Cut Pro video downloaded to flash drive

Tags: macbook-pro

I recently made a wedding video for my cousin, its about 6 minutes long. I can get it downloaded onto the flash drive but when I play it back it is really slow and laggy and doesnt really work? does anyone know why this is?

Comment: +1 For making a wedding video for your cousin. :)

Comment: Do you happen to know why this is?

Comment: Possibly give me a couple min

Comment: What quality are you exporting it in? Does it not play correctly on your Mac or on another device?

Comment: I exported it in 1080 on to my flash drive. When I then open it on the flash drive it is really laggy and hardly will play.

Comment: Bad USB ! try another one

Comment: Can you drive another flash drive the read speed maybe too slow. Additionally is it not playing correctly on your Mac or a different device?

Comment: I formatted the USB as MAC OS extended because my cousin has only mac computers. I have only tried it on my mac

Comment: Try another usb and another Mac. Report back with the results.

Answer (score 1):

Without all the details of your hardware (both the Mac and flash drive), the most likely cause is the transfer speed available from the flash drive to your Mac.

In this scenario you typically wouldn't opt to play the video from a flash drive, but rather just use the flash drive to transfer the video onto another device (such as your cousin's computer).

You should find that playing the video directly from a computer's internal drive, or from any modern external drive, should be fine. Note that by external drive I'm not referring to flash drives, but external HDDs or SSDs.

By way of a *similar* example, I recently had to produce an 8 minute video in FCP that needed to be viewable on a MS Surface device. It played fine on my Mac and fine on the Surface, but trying to play it from their 32GB flash drive resulted in a bad experience!